# CAN communication Tolerate dominant bit error

Tags: c, stm32, can-bus, hal

I'm working on a BMS project which uses CAN protocol for communication. Recently I'm facing some problems in CAN communication. I will explain the architecture of the BMS, CAN bus, and program with configurations.

**BMS architecture**
The BMS consists of one Master board and 3 slave boards. All 4 communicate through CAN. CAN driver is installed in all 4 boards. 120 ohms resistors are installed at each end of the CAN Bus.

The master is powered by DC DC converter and slave boards are powered directly by battery cells. But all the CAN bus is powered by the master board, which means that the slave CAN drivers are powered by the master board. D and R pins are connected to the Tx and Rx of the corresponding microcontrollers.

**Configuration**
CAN communication is set to 250Kbps. Online CAN bit Time calculation is used for bit timing and prescale.
Sample-point: 87.5%
SJW: 1
FrameFormat: ST Microelectronics bxCAN
Clocl rate: 48MHz(Slave) / 36MHz(Master) For better transmission accuracy, Low Speed Clock (LSE) is selected.

Time Triggered Communication mode: Disabled
Automatic Bus off management: Enable
Automatic Wake-Up Mode: Enable
Automatic Retransmission : Enable
Receive Fifo Locked Mode: Disable
Transmit Fifo Priority: Disable

**Problem**
When communication starts without any error, it works continuously. Even when I restart the BMS several tens of times, it works fine. The data capture using PCAN View is attached below. But when it has a problem, it starts with HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan2); function.

(I use STM HAP library for development)
When I start the BMS, after MX_CAN2_Init();
I set the CAN driver to high-speed CAN mode by pulling down the Rs pin to the ground.
Next I set the HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan2, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO1_MSG_PENDING | CAN_IT_ERROR_PASSIVE | CAN_IT_ERROR | CAN_IT_ERROR_WARNING | CAN_IT_LAST_ERROR_CODE);
So far so good.
When the program enters HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan2); function, it stops at *HAL_CAN_ERROR_TIMEOUT*.

I try to reinitialize the CAN peripheral by goback to setp1. The program runs in a loop.
The error I see in the PCAN view is *tolerate dominant bit error*.
I don't know what I'm missing.

What can be the possible causes of the problem? Is it because CAN peripherals are initialized at different times, and there is no other node to acknowledge the CAN_start() frames?

How can I identify the problem? How can I recover the bus from error? Is Automatic Bus-off management enough? Or should I restart the slaves by resetting them?

All your comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all ensure that you have a proper clock source for CAN. Failing to meet the clock accuracy criteria of CAN can lead to all manner of very strange problems. At 250kbps you cannot run some internal RC oscillator, particularly not a low res one as is common with many STM32. You need external quartz.

A common problem with CAN systems is that during power up, someone on the bus will always be the first to wake from its sleep. This node will start sending frames on the bus with nobody to ACK them. And so it gets an error, there will be an error frame, the error counter will increase. If that one fast node does this enough times to go error active/passive, you may reach a situation where it disconnects from sending data on the bus.

The common solution to this problem is to have each node listen to CAN errors and/or check if each transmission was OK. In case it fails to send data during a certain time, you should force that node's MCU to reset (by writing an incorrect sequence to the watchdog or letting it time out etc). This will give slower nodes a chance to catch up, plus the node which was reset will have its error counter reset too.

It is also very helpful for diagnostic purposes to have each node send out a "boot up" message once it's CAN bus is up and running. Then you can see in your CAN listener who is fast and who is slow. If you are implementing a OEM CAN protocol then I'd strongly recommend this approach - each node should at boot-up say "hi, I'm a node of type x with firmware version y and I'm ready to go!"

That being said, this could also be caused by some hardware issue like the mentioned clock issue, in which case SO is the wrong site to ask. https://electronics.stackexchange.com is overall more suitable for questions about CAN.

- More info about common CAN problems here: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)  (written by yours sincerely)
- Good info about CAN error frames [here](https://www.csselectronics.com/pages/can-bus-errors-intro-tutorial) (I'm not affiliated)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try your suggestions.